# What are the various lumped element dynamic system models called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, modeling, dynamics, circuits

What are the various lumped element dynamic system models called?  By lumped element dynamic system models, I mean the various nodal models comprised of things that look like capacitors, inductors, resistors, etc.  In other words, the models where these [analogies occur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogical_models#Dynamical_analogies). For example, for electrical systems, we just call them circuits.  In heat mass transfer, I sometimes see them called thermal nodal models or thermal circuits.

Basically, I'm trying to study [bond graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_graph), which talks about these analogies, but has its own notation.  Generally, in the bond graph literature, I see various diagrams and how they relate to bond graphs, but I'm not familiar with the various diagrams outside of electrical circuits.  For example, I see similar diagrams for mechanical systems with dampers.  I see diagrams for hydraulic components.  I'm pretty sure that there's even some kind of diagram that uses chemical potential for for current and molar flow for voltage.  The problem is that I'm not familiar with these diagrams and notation.  I'd look them up, but I'm not sure what they're called and I'm having a difficult time determining the common use names for the lumped element models in various domains.

Comment: I think they are agglomerated into what are called System Elements: http://youtu.be/8U3QvviaMJQ

Comment: the hechanical analogy a spring mass damper system is called a lumped system.